# Wamp server Apache does not starts

Tags: php, apache, sockets, wamp

I'm working with wamp server 5-6 years. I bought a new laptop with windows 8.1. I installed wamp server and 3-4 about I haven't problem. But today my wamp server not starting. When I was doing my research I could not find anything related to my problem.

1. I checked and the IIS ins't installed on Windows features
2. I uninstalled skype ( which using the `port 80` )
3. I re-install 2 times the wamp server and the last install I reinstall also the MS Visual c++ redistributable
4. I deleted previous the install all files ( the directory `c:/wamp` )
5. I checked the "Web Deployment Agent Service i" aren't running

Please not that : I'm not changed anything on my pc... and yet I still have the problem.

Also in windows logs I saw the following errors for apache:

> (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by
>   its access permissions. 
> AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
>   address [::]:80  ( 2 times )
>   AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
>        AH00015: Unable to open log

Any idea or help is very helpful... Thank you for all replies

Comment: sounds like firewall

Comment: Rafael the wamp runned 4-5 months correctly. Today I tried to connect to another wireless and now the apapche always is orange and not runs. Can you help me

Comment: You can use `netstat -ano` from a prompt to check if another (and which) process is using port 80. Sounds like another program is using the port which prevents WAMP from starting.

Comment: Rafael I disabled the firewal both for private and public networks. But the same problem exists

Comment: it's simply a port issue just check your port 80 like @Bjorn advised and you'll be good to go.  When all else fails, just program apache to start on a different port.  In your WAMP control panel

Comment: Bjorn i tried your command netstat -ano | findstr :80 and the result is  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: Rafael te port 80 not used from another proccess... This looks like a socket problem

Comment: Most def. not a socket issue. As the line `TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 4` from your prev. comment shows. Just kill the processes which are running on port 80 (0.0.0.0:80 and [::]:80).

Comment: The process PID=4 is the SYSTEM. I can't kill this... I changed the port to 8080 and the problem solved... But how can I run this with port 80

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the system?

Comment: I rebooted also the system but the problem exists...

Comment: Have you tried this? http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,85116,85116 It suggests disabling ipv6 support by changing `listen 80` in httpd.conf to `listen 0.0.0.0:80`.

Comment: did you install skype recently? skype sometimes use 80 port (not sure why). close the skype and try again.

Comment: I uninstalled the skype and I have the same problem. I changed the listen as listen 80, listen 0.0.0.0:80, listen 127.0.0.1:80 with IPv6 disabled but without solution...

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the solution. I disabled both the IPv6 and again the SQL Server reporting service and I changed the port again to 80 from 8080 and now it's working. Thanks all you for your helps